# jQuery get value of appended input after change it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a jQuery code, I want to do calculations on the fields that appended
The example is as follows:
I have a product and its price, quantity and total price
The total price is calculated by multiplying the price by the quantity
When I make a jQuery code to calculate the total it works normally on the default element that appears when the page loads
But it doesn't work for appended fields via the add line button

The problem more clearly is that the value of the appended input cannot be accessed after changing it

[image]

```
<tr class="product-tr" data-product="1">
<td class="product-key">1</td>
<td>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="product-name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{% translate 'Write product info' %}">
        <button type="button" class="remove-product btn btn-sm btn-light-danger" disabled>
            -
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="add-product btn btn-sm btn-light-success">
            +
        </button>
    </div>

    <input hidden name="product[1]['id']" type="number" class="product-id form-control">
</td>
<td>
    <input name="product[1]['price']" id="product-price-1" type="number" class="product-price form-control">
</td>
<td>
    <input name="product[1]['quantity']" id="product-quantity-1" min="1" value="1" type="number" class="product-quantity form-control">
</td>
<td>
    <input name="product[1]['total']" id="product-total-1" type="number" class="product-total form-control border-0 bg-light" disabled>
</td>
```

And this is jQuery code for append new row

```
function recalculate_elements(){
    $( ".product-tr" ).each(function(index , e ) {
        index = index+1
        $(e).attr('data-product',index)
        $('.product-key', e).text(index)

        $('.product-id', e).attr('name', "product["+index+"]['id']")

        $('.product-price', e).attr('name', "product["+index+"]['price']")
        $('.product-price', e).attr('id', "product-price-"+index)

        $('.product-quantity', e).attr('name', "product["+index+"]['quantity']")
        $('.product-quantity', e).attr('id', "product-quantity-"+index)

        $('.product-total', e).attr('name', "product["+index+"]['total']")
        $('.product-total', e).attr('id', "product-total-"+index)
    })
}
```

and this is jQuery code to calculate total price

```
$('.invoice-table').on("keyup change", ".product-price, .product-quantity" , function() {
    parent_tr = $(this).parents('tr')
    id = parent_tr.attr('data-product')

    price = $('.product-price', parent_tr)
    quantity = $('.product-quantity', parent_tr)
    total = $('.product-total', parent_tr)

     alert(price.val())

    total.val(price.val() * quantity.val())

})
```

This code getting null value

```
 alert(price.val())
```

Comment: It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/4njfes6b/1/

Comment: Yeah its working for first row but not working for appended rows

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: I fix it after add empty ids and names to appended elements
https://jsfiddle.net/MohamedSlimane/ktbfoc1g/67/

Comment: The function for displaying the total only cares about the classes.